# If $x$ is irreducible, and $x\nmid y$, why are $x$ and $y$ relatively prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $x$ be an irreducible element of a principal ideal domain $D$. If $y$ is an element of $D$ and $x$ does not divide $y$, show that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.

Comment: I failed to show that gcd(x,y) = 1 using the fact that x is irreducible

Comment: How did you fail?  Can you show some of your steps in your question?  Did you use any properties of the principle ideal domain in your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

$(x)$ is a maximal ideal, and if $d = \text{gcd}(x,y)$, then $$(x) \subset (d)$$ Furthermore, if $x\nmid y$, then $y \notin (x)$, and so $$(x) \neq (d)$$ Hence, $(d) = R$ and so $d$ is a unit - which is equivalent to saying that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.

Comment: could you be more explicit? I still don't get it. thanks

Comment: @Alex : I've edited my post.